# Is there a way to replace outliers with NaN in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I want to replace outliers with NaN so that I can concat that dataframe with the other dataframe where I don't want to remove the outliers. Following is the dataset. I want to perform **outlier removal** only on 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'ap_hi', 'ap_lo'.

```
id  age gender  height  weight  ap_hi   ap_lo   cholesterol gluc    smoke   alco    active  cardio
988 22469   1   155     69.0    130     80      2          2        0       0   1   0
989 14648   1   163     71.0    110     70      1          1        0       0   1   1
990 21901   1   165     70.0    120     80      1          1        0       0   1   0
991 14549   2   165     85.0    120     80      1          1        1       1   1   0
992 23393   1   155     62.0    120     80      1          1        0       0   1   0
```

I tried the following method but it's taking all columns into consideration:

```
from scipy import stats
df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Could you give some example data, how you are identifying outliers etc

Comment: When a row contains an outlier attribute, do you want to make NaN only that attribute or the entire row?

Comment: Hi, orlp, I want to make only that attribute as NaN and not the entire row!

Comment: What do you consider an outlier?